# Load images via UNC in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Is it possible to show media from a UNC path in silverlight?  I know I can't load items from the client side, but I have access to the files on the web server via unc.  I have a webservice that shows all of the available files, but I need to play the movies and show the images and I am not sure its even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  You need to expose the media to the client via web URLs (this is assuming that your SL client is running in a web page).

Comment: Could I do the file:// address to them?

Comment: Maybe, but only if the Silverlight client is also running from a file:// URL.  Otherwise, it is considered cross-zone and is disallowed.

Comment: Not disallowed, you have to have the cross domain policy file on the domain that is being requested.

Comment: I didn't say cross-domain; I said cross-zone.  You cannot request a file:// URL from an HTTP-hosted web page.  That would be madness, and a big security hole.

Comment: True. Although Silverlight has no concept of zones

Comment: Perhaps not, but the host browser does.

Comment: How irrelevant to Silverlight. Silverlight can request across same domain or across domains with a client access policy file. Zones play no part in a Silverlight app.

Comment: You consider to misunderstand.  Zones have nothing to do with domains.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially no.

The only way that Silverlight can retrieve files is:

[IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts8hk0(VS.71).aspx) which allows Silverlight to store a few MB of data on the client's computer.
HTTP requests as long as the originating server has the appropriate [cross domain policy file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838250(VS.95).aspx) in place.  If you serve the images/files from the same domain as the Silverlight application is hosted on, no cross domain policy file is required.

The easiest way you can get this working is to set up a web server that can serve up your files over HTTP.